# Perl array overriding

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, overriding

I am trying to do sum of the array in my perl code but I was not able to get the right output.

Here is my sample code

```
use File::Find::Rule;
use Date::Parse;

my ($dir,   $type,  $fh,    $line,  $str_1,
    $str_2,$str_3, $str_4);

my @array;

$dir = '/dir/test/';
$type = '*';
$str_1           = 'somestr1';
$str_2           = 'somestr2';
$str_3           = 'somestr3';
$str_4           = 'somestr4';

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name($type)->in($dir);

open $out, '>>', "output_log" or die "Unable to open 'output_log' : $!";
print $out "\Logs \n";
print $out "--------------------------\n";
close $out or die "Unable to finish writing output_log : $!";

for my $file (@files) {

    open $fh,  '<',  $file        or die "can't open $file: $!";
    open $out, '>>', "output_log" or die "Unable to open 'output_log' : $!";

    while ( $line = <$fh> ) {

        if ( $line !~ /$str_1/ && $line =~ /$str_2/ ) 
         {
              @array = $somevar  # result of this loop 2,3   
         }

       if ( $line !~ /$str_3/ && $line =~ /$str_4/ ) 
         {
            @array = $somevar   #result of this loop 2,3,4,5,6
         } 


    }

    close $out or die "Unable to finish writing output_log : $!";
}
```

## So Here is what I want

```
@array = (2,3,2,3,4,5,6)
and sum of @array
```

but unfornately,if i print this array that is running each and every line but instead i want to write a loop which stores the result in array from both if blocks..
now the code is overriding the @array in the second if block. Hope I made this clear!! Please help

Comment: I hope you have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of your program? They are essential in every Perl program that you write. And you must not declare all of your variables at the top of the file, as it makes simple bugs much harder to find. That used to be necessary for very old C compilers, but I can't think of any language now where it isn't better to declare every variable where it is first defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@array = ...` overwrites the contents of the array. Use [push](http://p3rl.org/push) to add elements to an existing array.

For sum, see `sum` (or `sum0`) in [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util).

Comment: and from the description, it sounds like they need two different arrays in the while loop, one for each if condition